# Почему ORDER BY не срабатывает при использовании UNION в mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Привет.

Вопрос по mysql. Какие есть тонкости использования UNION в mysql?

Столкнулся с такой штукой - у меня есть два селекта, первый из них содержит `ORDER BY`. между селектами `UNION` стоит. сортировки в первом селекте почему-то НЕ происходит. То есть, выводит без сортировки, и ошибку не выдает никакую.

Создал базу данных

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE asd;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.48 sec)

mysql> SELECT table_name,table_comment FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables WHERE table_schema='asd';
Empty set (0.05 sec)

mysql> USE asd;
Database changed

mysql> CREATE TABLE ukraine (
    -> name CHAR(30) NOT NULL);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.84 sec)
```

Создал таблицу ukraine

```
mysql> INSERT INTO ukraine VALUES ('Kiev'),('Lvov'),('Kharkov'),('Poltava');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.15 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM ukraine;
+---------+
| name    |
+---------+
| Kiev    |
| Lvov    |
| Kharkov |
| Poltava |
+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Создал таблицу russia

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE russia (
    -> name CHAR(30) NOT NULL);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.25 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO russia VALUES ('Moskva'),('Belgorod'),('Krasnodar'),('Sochi');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.11 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM russia;
+-----------+
| name      |
+-----------+
| Moskva    |
| Belgorod  |
| Krasnodar |
| Sochi     |
+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Объединяю с помощью UNION

mysql> (SELECT * FROM ukraine) UNION (SELECT * FROM russia);
+-----------+
| name      |
+-----------+
| Kiev      |
| Lvov      |
| Kharkov   |
| Poltava   |
| Moskva    |
| Belgorod  |
| Krasnodar |
| Sochi     |
+-----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Объединяю с помощью UNION c ORDER BY, не срабатывает

```
mysql> (SELECT * FROM ukraine ORDER BY name) UNION (SELECT * FROM russia);
+-----------+
| name      |
+-----------+
| Kiev      |
| Lvov      |
| Kharkov   |
| Poltava   |
| Moskva    |
| Belgorod  |
| Krasnodar |
| Sochi     |
+-----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Объединяю с помощью UNION c ORDER BY, не срабатывает

```
mysql> (SELECT * FROM ukraine) UNION (SELECT * FROM russia ORDER BY name);
+-----------+
| name      |
+-----------+
| Kiev      |
| Lvov      |
| Kharkov   |
| Poltava   |
| Moskva    |
| Belgorod  |
| Krasnodar |
| Sochi     |
+-----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Объединяю с помощью UNION c ORDER BY, который ставлю в КОНЕЦ, сработало

```
mysql> (SELECT * FROM ukraine) UNION (SELECT * FROM russia) ORDER BY name;
+-----------+
| name      |
+-----------+
| Belgorod  |
| Kharkov   |
| Kiev      |
| Krasnodar |
| Lvov      |
| Moskva    |
| Poltava   |
| Sochi     |
+-----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Вопрос - почему ORDER BY срабатывает только в конце? Он, по идее, он должен срабатывать внутри каждого запроса.**

Comment: Нет, не должен. Вернее внутри то запроса он срабатывает, но если в самом конце запроса нет своего собственного order by - то порядок выдачи не определен. Определитесь, как должны выглядеть выходные данные и можно будет придумать правильный order by для всего запроса в целом

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Представьте, что каждый подзапрос вставляет данные в некоторую временную таблицу, а потом общий селект эти данные вытягивает. Тогда очевидно, что нет разницы в каком порядке были вставлены. Учитывается только итоговый порядок выборки

Иными словами

```
SELECT ....
UNION
SELECT ....
UNION
SELECT ....
UNION
SELECT ....
```

Трансформируется в некоторое подобие такого

```
INSERT INTO `temp` SELECT .....;
INSERT INTO `temp` SELECT .....;
INSERT INTO `temp` SELECT .....;
INSERT INTO `temp` SELECT .....;

SELECT * FROM `temp`;
```

Тогда понятно, что какие бы ORDER BY Вы не указывали в промежуточных запросах последний селект будет использовать свой порядок сортировки

Comment: можете посоветовать хороший источник, где разжеван вопрос про подзапросы?

Comment: мне не очень понятен ответ. если не трудно, то напишите, пожалуйста, более подробно

Comment: @Dimon Чем не устраивает официальная документация? Там все внятно написано

Comment: мне там ничего не понятно. на английском пишут. если бы я понимал, что к чему, то не задавал бы здесь вопросы

Comment: @Dimon Я доуточнил ответ

Answer (score 3):

Вы делаете именно `union`, не более простой и глупый `union all`. `union` без указания какой именно это `union` выполняет `union distinct`. Т.е. попытается удалить дубликаты строк из объединяемых множеств.

Обычно это само по себе не то поведение, на что вы рассчитывали и почти всегда когда говорят про `union` хотят видеть на самом деле `union all`. Если все строки разные, это просто лишняя операция, если есть совпадающие строки - то их вы потеряете из выборки и это может быть совсем не тем, что вы хотели получить.

И да, поиск дублирующих строк изменяет сортировку набора строк потому что он так сделан.

Фактически `union all` просто склеит две выборки одну за другой и не затронет сортировку. Не помню исключений для запроса верхнего уровня, но да, это не гарантируется стандартом. Если порядок критично важен то имеет смысл пересортировать после объединения:

```
(SELECT 1 as sortf, name FROM ukraine)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT 2 as sortf, name FROM russia)
ORDER BY sortf, name;
```

Этот запрос гарантированно выдаст сначала записи из таблицы ukraine, отсортированные по названию, затем - из russia, тоже отсортированные по названию.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. у меня нет дубликатов. если поменять union на union all, то ничего не поменяется. я пробовал

Comment: Нет, стандарт SQL _не гарантирует_, что в результате выполнения union all в начале будет выданное первой частью и строго за ним - выданное второй частью. Стандарт дает гарантию _только_ на итоговый `order by`.

Comment: @Mike об этом я и написал, что не гарантирует и как на уровне запроса задать именно это поведение. Стоит переформулировать мысль?

Answer (score 3):

> почему ORDER BY срабатывает только в конце? Он, по идее, он должен срабатывать внутри каждого запроса

А с чего ты решил, что не срабатывает? срабатывает... просто между этим срабатыванием и попаданием к тебе результата много чего ещё происходит - в том числе и влияющего на итоговый порядок отдачи записей.

======

Уже много сказано, большинство - правильно, в полном соответствии с [документацией](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html). Просто явно сформулирую основное, как мне кажется, следствие вышеописанных фактов:

**Если в отдельном запросе, входящем в объединение по UNION, нет LIMIT, то использование ORDER BY в нём бессмысленно, результат сортировки всё равно будет проигнорирован.**

Да, не кидайте в меня огрызками, есть и другие случаи, когда ORDER BY в отдельном запросе имеет смысл. Например, если этот запрос использует переменные - скажем, для эмуляции не реализованных пока оконных функций. Но это крайне редкие случаи, и для авторов таких запросов поведение сортировки в UNION вряд ли является секретом.

Answer (score 2):

Union работает совместно с множеством. Union не может работать с отсортированными данными.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms180026.aspx
На данном сайте указано, что нельзя объединять сортированные данные.
SQL в принципе заточен на  работу в реляционном стиле , то есть с множеством целиком. Попытка работать в итерационном стиле приводит к замедлению работы поэтому Cursor работает значительно медленнее,чем если обойтись только реляционными средствами.

Comment: Вообще-то ТС в самом начале явно указал СУБД. И это был ни разу не MS SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Union работает во всех СУБД одинаково, так как совместим с стандартом, в mdsn приведено на примерах и доступно.

Comment: Только внешний эффект от работы UNION одинаков во всех СУБД. И то исключительно в той части, в которой отдаваемый им результат детерминирован. А во всём остальном - и особенно во внутренних механизмах работы,- у каждой СУБД своя реализация, со своими особенностями и заморочками.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста на примерах чем отличается ms sql от mysql в части по реализации union

Comment: Они в этом для меня абсолютно одинаковы - я не знаю, как именно реализованы UNION в каждом из серверов. А если Вас интересует различие в **результатах** их работы - попробуйте сделать UNION ALL двух выборок из одной таблицы, не имеющей ни одного уникального индекса, с разными условиями отбора, и посмотрите на сортировку результата на обоих серверах. Потом попробуйте сделать UNION DISTINCT и ещё раз посмотрите на сортировку результата.